# What are these tools in Word? Grid in ruler and pins

Tags: microsoft-word

Can somebody tell what are these tools? I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krj49etxoXE) about ruler but that grid wasn't covered.

[Pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXfmD.png)

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5JIg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridlines can help you align objects on a page. Their value is primarily for objects that you want text wrapping around them, and again, you want the objects all aligned evenly. Below is an example.

[image]

Gridlines will not print nor will they transfer to a PDF version of the document.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very useful feature I didn't know exists. But still, items in screenshot isn't related with these gridelines. This isn't my document in screenshots, hence, I didn't know how to create these things myself. But I figured out that it's a table with hidden borders.